# Faire de la bonne cuisine demande un certain temps

Tags: traduction

I'm reading an English book which features a French menu as a random quote.

When I look at the sentence:

> Faire de la bonne cuisine demande un certain temps.

And the context I don't see how the author gets the English translation of:

> Good cooking fakes time.

Is the author correct in his interpretation and if so can anyone elaborate on what I'm missing here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would help us cover the "what am I missing" part of your question if you could give us an idea (even a rough one) of how you would have gone about translating it.

Comment: @PapaPoule my translation was the same as Alexandre's answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Good cooking fakes time*

is a (very unfortunate) typo. The correct translation of *"Faire de la bonne cuisine demande un certain temps"* is:

> *Good cooking **t**akes time*

or, even better:

> *Good cooking **t**akes some time*

Comment: Yes that was my interpretation too.

Comment: This typo has been corrected in later printings.